# Eclipse : missing org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-juno

I try to download Eclipse Juno (I havedownloaded Java version and install Web Development and Enterprise Development toolkits). After that, I install Google Plugin for Eclipse. When Eclipse check dependency, it notices error :

> Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2
>   3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I have google many times, but still cannot solve this problem. Who has experience in this problem, please tell me. This annoy me so much :(

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" checkbox is checked in the Eclipse, Install New Software dialog.

Answer (score 6):

I had a different problem that lead to this error:

My fresh install of Eclipse Juno did not have the Juno repository in the list at all.

To fix this, simply add this repository's URL (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/) to the "Work with:" edit box once, before installing the Google Plugins (and, of course, also make sure that the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" checkbox is checked, as described by d60402).

Answer (score 1):

My case also differs in that I'm using Rational Application Developer (RAD) for WebSphere and I was trying to install Kotlin, but the solution was the same as the one described by Markus A.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps
Help -> install new software -> add below url -> next
https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest